# Microsoft translator nb-NO translates fine, but supported language api call does not list as supported language

Tags: c#, microsoft-translator

I would like to check if a language is supported by Microsoft Translator, before sending the request of to translate text.

I make a call to this api:
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/GetLanguagesForTranslate

and it returns a list of languages. One of them is: **"no"** for Norweigan.

My application has support for **nb-NO**... so my language check essentially comes down to this code:

```
string language = "nb-NO";
this.cachedSupportedLanguages = string[] { "no" };
return this.cachedSupportedLanguages.Contains(language);
```

The issue i'm having is if i send the request off to this api with **nb-NO** as the "to Language", the translation falls back to Norweigan:
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=textToTranslate&from=fromLanguage&to=toLanguage ...

...but **I** cannot find a way of pre-checking if a language is supported because even if i do:

```
new CultureInfo(language)
```

It doesn't have any knowledge of the language being able to fall back to Norweigan.

Any ideas how i can check this in a better way than an explicit `switch`?

---

**Edit**

> The cultures have a hierarchy, such that the parent of a specific
>   culture is a neutral culture and the parent of a neutral culture is
>   the InvariantCulture. The Parent property returns the neutral culture
>   associated with a specific culture.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.71).aspx

If i do this:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(language);

// For languages like en-US
if (this.cachedSupportedLanguages.Any(x => x.Equals(cultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
{
    return true;
}

// For languages like nb-NO where the explicit language is not supported but its parent culture is
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cultureInfo.Parent.ToString()))
{
    if (cultureInfo.Parent.IsNeutralCulture)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cultureInfo.Parent.Parent.ToString()))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cultureInfo.Parent.Parent.CompareInfo.ToString()))
            {
                return this.cachedSupportedLanguages.Any(x => x.Equals(cultureInfo.Parent.Parent.CompareInfo.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get a true... But i do not fully understand if the Parent is always going to be a safe bet to go to for this information?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Microsoft translator method that returns the information you need. The data is returned as JSON. You can get supported languages for text translation, speech translation and text to speech in one api call. You also get more information.

Learn about it and try it out at: http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/languages.html

Answer (score 0):

GetLanguagesForTranslate returns `nb` for Norwegian, not `no` as stated in the post. Go to http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/languages.html, click Try it, and see this in the result:

```
"nb": {
  "name": "Norwegian",
  "dir": "ltr"
},
```

One approach would be to keep a table with the result of the GetLanguagesForTranslate. First look up your culture code directly, and if no match, then look for a match on the Parent. Parent should be reliable for this purpose. This will let your code work for those supported languages like `sr-Cyrl`, `sr-Latn`, `zh-Hans`, and `zh-Hant`, and fall back to the neutral when the qualified name isn't available.